# Ruby ternary operator in erb?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, ternary-operator

How can I make this code look better:

```
<%=raw manuscript.uploaded_to_s3? ? "<span style=\"color:green;\">" : "<span style=\"color:red;\">" %>
```

That is, can the HTML go outside of the ERB block making this easier to read?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<span style="color:<%= manuscript.uploaded_to_s3? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
```

I would advocate a CSS class rather than style attribute 8P:

```
<span class="<%= manuscript.uploaded_to_s3? ? 'green' : 'red' %>">
```